# Add a feature for similarity comparison

Tags: feature-request, review, answers, duplicate-questions

It'd be nice if answers which are an exact copy of an existing (possibly upvoted) answer or contain large substring of such an answer and few own text - which should be a comment on the copied answer - are hard to spot in review because only the question and the answer is displayed.

A warning that the above described similarity has been detected (by an algorithm which can be quite simple for starters) would be helpful and avoid that those unwanted answers get into the system/stay in there for long time as easy as possible.

Comment: AFAIK moderators are notified when multiple identical answers are posted.

Comment: @gothdo only if the same user posted both. This might be helpful for catching plagiarism.

Comment: This is potentially a good idea, but most cases of plagiarism are from sources not within the SE, and it's a little bit hard for humans to discern plagiarism, let alone machines. +1 for now

Comment: @Rubisco Agreed. I'm not proposing a deterministic/reliable way to find plagiats - this is, as you said, complicated. I'm really up against simple copies which can be detected with a string comparison or substring search. This would be covered by the proposal linked as duplicate, but this solution could be implemented as a base/test and then be extended, as well.

Comment: I support this, on Ask Ubuntu, I find quite a lot of post that are copy / paste of other answers from people looking for quick rep.